# try catch in a do while loop

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, do-while

The program asks for the user input for the double num 1 and double num 2
and if there is an exception I want it to ask again for the input of num 1 and num 2

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double num1, num2;
    int error = 0;
    int text;
    System.out.print("Enter 4 ");
        text = sc.nextInt();

    do{

        try{

    if(text == 4){
            System.out.print("Enter number 1: ");
            num1 = sc.nextDouble();
            System.out.print("Enter number 2: ");
            num2 = sc.nextDouble();
            double quotient = num1/num2;
            System.out.println("The Quotient of "+num1 + "/" +num2+ " = "+quotient);
            }
        }catch(Exception ex){ 
            System.out.println("You've entered wrong input");
                error = 1;
        }                                  

          }while(error == 1);
}
```

then when I try the code if it will catch the exceptions by inputing string in the num1 or num 2 I'm having this infinite loop :
 `Enter number 1: You've entered wrong input
Enter number 1: You've entered wrong input
Enter number 1: You've entered wrong input
Enter number 1: You've entered wrong input
Enter number 1: You've entered wrong input`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] (note the "complete" bit).

Comment: Where do you obtain that double?

Comment: Your code would benefit by declaring and (re)using a separate method that gets input from the user until the user enters valid data.

Answer (score 3):

You need to reset the `error` variable inside the loop

```
do {
    error = 0;
    //...
} while(error == 1);
```

Comment: still having the loop

Comment: @Pon You need to add `error = 0;` inside the `do while` loop.

Comment: I did put it inside the do while loop but it still loops

Comment: @Pon What is the exception caught in the `catch`?

Comment: InputMismatchException since I was trying to input a string into an double data type

Answer (score 1):

Its in C# but relatively similar :)

```
public class Program
{
  private static double ReadUserInput (string message) 
  {
    // This is a double
    // The '?' makes it nullable which is easier to work with
    double? input = null;

    do 
    {
      // Write message out
      Console.Write(message);
      // Read answer
      var inputString = Console.ReadLine();
      // Temp variable for the number
      double outputNumber = 0;
      // Try parse the number
      if (double.TryParse(inputString, out outputNumber))
      {
        // The number was parsable as a double so lets set the input variable
        input = outputNumber;
      }
      else
      {
        // Tell the user the number was invalid
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry bud, but '" + inputString + "' is not a valid double");
      }
    } 
    while (input == null); // Keep running until the input variable is actually set by the above

    // Return the output
    return (double)input;
  }

  public static void Main()
  {
    // Read a number
    var num1 = ReadUserInput("Enter number 1:");
    // Read another number
    var num2 = ReadUserInput("Enter number 2:");
    // Show the calculation
    Console.WriteLine("Answer: " + (num1*num2));
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4Ae7u1)

And for the actual code (in JAVA):

```
public class JavaFiddle 
{
  public static void main (String[] args) 
  {
    // Read a number
    Double num1 = ReadUserInput("Enter number 1:");
    // Read another number
    Double num2 = ReadUserInput("Enter number 2:");
    // Show the calculation
    System.out.println("Answer: " + (num1*num2));
  }

  public static Double ReadUserInput (String message) 
  {
    java.util.Scanner inputScanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
    Double input = null;

    do 
    {
      // Write message out
      System.out.println(message);
      // Read answer
      String inputString = inputScanner.nextLine();
      try 
      {
        // Try parse the number
        input = Double.parseDouble(inputString);
      } 
      catch (NumberFormatException e) 
      {
        // Tell the user the number was invalid
        System.out.println("Sorry bud, but '" + inputString + "' is not a valid double");
      }
    } 
    while (input == null); // Keep running until the input variable is actually set by the above

    // Return the output
    return input;
  }
}
```

Comment: There os no `C#` tag under question. Why you decide to post unhelpful answer?

Comment: it's look like a good solution , but you should write it in `java`

Comment: Its more of the process and how to write this in OOP style and the way the process is running was where i was going with the answer rather than the code.

There isn't much difference between JAVA and C# but as I haven't done JAVA in ages, I would rather post working code than something that may work or if it doesn't, confuse someone - which is worse.

I'll look at re-writing in JAVA to be more in line with the Q :)

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to utilize exception handling. Just use `Scanner.hasNextDouble()` method to find out if actual user input is double, otherwise continue the cycle.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double num1, num2;
        num1 = readDouble(1, sc);
        num2 = readDouble(2, sc);
        double quotient = num1/num2;
        System.out.println("The Quotient of " + num1 + "/" + num2 + " = " + quotient);
    }

    private static double readDouble(int i, Scanner sc) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter number " + i + ": ");
            if (!sc.hasNextDouble()) {
                System.out.println("You've entered wrong input");
                sc.next();
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
        return sc.nextDouble();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry for not putting it in the code, but there is a multiple else if's there, because I want the user to define what method he/she want's to do.

I tried the code you commented by adding the boolean continue and break it doesnt have any errors but the loop is not starting when I inputed  String instead of double

Comment: I missed `sc.next();`

Comment: That fixes it .

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to test if there is no error:

```
}while(error != 1);
```

or

```
}while(error == 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a method for the input which calls itself, if the input is invalid.

```
double getInput(Scanner sc) {
    try {
        double num = sc.nextDouble();
        return num;
    } catch(Exception ex) { 
        System.out.println("You've entered wrong input");
        return getInput(sc);
    }    
}
```

And call this method twice in your other method.

Answer (score 0):

it may look ugly , but here is a way to do it

```
  do
  {
    if(...)
    {

      boolean successReading = false;
      while(!successReading)
      {
        try
        {
          System.out.print("Enter number 1: ");
          num1 = sc.nextDouble();
          System.out.print("Enter number 2: ");
          num2 = sc.nextDouble();

          successReading = true;

          double product = num1*num2;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
          successReading = false;  
        }
      }

    }
  }while(...)
```

Comment: hey it's a noob question but what is inside that last while ?

Comment: your condition to keep your `do while` looping . but let me ask you a question why you write this `if(text == 4){`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `sc.next();` inside `catch` block.

`nextDouble` method doesn't clear buffer in case of exception. So next time you invoke it you get same error because old input is still in buffer.

Also you need to reset your `error` flag in the beginning of the loop.

Comment: Then mark it as accepted. It helps find right answer to those who have same problem as you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put `sc.next();` in the catch so it will clear your scanner variable and it will ask for an input