# exception handling resulting in infite loop(java)

Tags: java, exception, user-input

Hello I am a Java beginner.I wanted to make a method that takes an integer between 1 and 9. I am using the exception handler so that it can deal with wrong or mismatched input but it seems that it is only executing the statement "choice = input.nextInt()" once and my loop goes to infinite because of it.

Code is below:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Player{
    private int[] over;
    private int choice;
    private int coordinates[];
    private static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);


    public Player(){
        over = new int[5];
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            over[i] = 1;
        }
        coordinates = new int[2];
        coordinates[0] = coordinates[1] = -1;
    }


    public void getChoice(){
            int choice = -1;
            boolean inputIsOk;
            do{
                System.out.print("Enter Your Choice: ");
                inputIsOk = true;
                try{
                    choice = input.nextInt();
                }
                catch(InputMismatchException e){
                    System.out.println("Invalid choice");
                    inputIsOk = false;
                }
                if(choice < 1 || choice > 9){
                    System.out.println("Enter Choice In Range(1-9)");
                    inputIsOk = false;
                }
            }while(!inputIsOk);
            System.out.println("You Entered "+choice);
    }
}
```

And here is the testclass:

```
public class TestPlayer{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Player p1 = new Player();
        p1.getChoice();
    }
}
```

Here is the ouput:
First case When only integral choice is entered

```
harsh@harsh-Inspiron-3558:~/java/oxgame$ javac TestPlayer.java 
harsh@harsh-Inspiron-3558:~/java/oxgame$ java TestPlayer 
Enter Your Choice: 10
Enter Choice In Range(1-9)
Enter Your Choice: -1
Enter Choice In Range(1-9)
Enter Your Choice: 55
Enter Choice In Range(1-9)
Enter Your Choice: 5
You Entered 5
```

And Second when I enter wrong input:

```
Enter Your Choice: 10
Enter Choice In Range(1-9)
Enter Your Choice: 55
Enter Choice In Range(1-9)
Enter Your Choice:g
Enter Your Choice: Invalid choice
Enter Choice In Range(1-9)
Enter Your Choice: Invalid choice
Enter Choice In Range(1-9)
Enter Your Choice: Invalid choice
Enter Choice In Range(1-9)
Enter Your Choice: Invalid choice
Enter Choice In Range(1-9)
Enter Your Choice: Invalid choice
Enter Choice In Range(1-9)
Enter Your Choice: Invalid choice
Enter Choice In Range(1-9)
Enter Your Choice: Invalid choice
Enter Choice In Range(1-9)
Enter Your Choice: Invalid choice
Enter Choice In Range(1-9)
and it goes on....
```

Please help me,Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [try catch in a do while loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45348919/try-catch-in-a-do-while-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work

```
try{ 
       choice = Integer.parseInt(input.next());
   } 
catch(NumberFormatException e){
    System.out.println("Invalid choice");
    inputIsOk = false;
}
```

Reason Being:
Say Scanner read an Object from stream say `typeCache`. Until it won't get an Integer Value, buffer will not be flushed and `typeCache` will hold `String` until it is read using `next()`(or any equivalent).

Code Of `Scanner` class:

```
    public int nextInt() {
    return nextInt(defaultRadix);
}

public int nextInt(int radix) {
    // Check cached result
    if ((typeCache != null) && (typeCache instanceof Integer)
        && this.radix == radix) {
        int val = ((Integer)typeCache).intValue();
        useTypeCache();
        return val;
    }.......
```

Or
Simply add `input.next();` in your catch block and it will clear `typeCache` automatically.

Comment: Sir the explanation is precise but it is more technical, as I am a beginner can you explain in simpler way?But thanks for the solution.

Comment: In Simple Words::: Lets say there's a buffer which holds the data coming from input steam. When we read data from buffer it gets flushed to receive new data from stream. By using nextInt() what it does is, if buffer holds Integer data then it returns data and clears buffer else Scanner will wait until buffer is read.

Comment: for example:
write now `typeCache="g"` (If you enter g as input).
If we use `nextInt()` then it will check whether `typeCache` contains int or not. If it contains int then that value will be returned and `typeCache` will hold/reset-to next value from stream. Else, `typeCache` will contain 'g' until next()/nextLine() method is not called.

Comment: Thank you very much, You helped a lot.

Answer (score 1):

if you change catch clause as below:

```
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    input.next();
    System.out.println("Invalid choice");
    inputIsOk = false;
}
```

this will work, `input.next();` i don't know exactly why, 
the old code -when you enter g- was just executing this `choice = input.nextInt();` as if it still hold the same value, it did not wait for user input, calling `next()` fixed this.